# AppAuth RedirectUriReceiverActivity not being catch

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, appauth

I'm new to Android and am trying to make an app authenticate using oauth2 on a website (in which I only can setup the integration, getting a ClientId and defining the redirect_uri). This website only allows Uris as a redirect. It does not allow a custom scheme like: "br.com.myapp:/oauth2redirect".
Given this, I setup "http://br.com.myapp/oauth2redirect" as my redirect_uri at the site.

I am using AppAuth:

`implementation 'net.openid:appauth:0.8.1'`

In my manifest file, I've added the intent-filter below:

```xml
<activity
    android:name="net.openid.appauth.RedirectUriReceiverActivity"
    tools:node="replace">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:scheme="http"
            android:host="br.com.myapp"
            android:pathPrefix="/oauth2redirect" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In my "build.gradle", I setup:

```
manifestPlaceholders = [
        'appAuthRedirectScheme': 'br.com.myapp'
]
```

Well, the app opens a CustomTabsIntent in which the target oauth provider website is opened. I'm able to insert user/pass. I'm then redirected to another page on the provider's site where I need to accept the authentication and then a blank page opens with the message:

```
This site can't be reached
br.com.myapp's server IP address could not be found
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

The address it is pointing to is my redirect uri: http://br.com.myapp/oauth2redirect?code=xxxx&state=xxxx

As far as I understand, this is correct. The problem is that my app is not catching this intent. Any tips?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to set `android:exported` to `"true"`, see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported

Example:

```
<activity
    android:name="net.openid.appauth.RedirectUriReceiverActivity"
    tools:node="replace"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
...
```